# Use Sass variable defined in an Angular library

Tags: angular, sass

I wrote an Angular library (angular 14) `my-lib` which contains a styles.scss file

```
.test-css-class {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

$test-variable: lightgreen;
```

In the Angular application which uses that library, I imported the sass file of my library :

`@import url('my-lib/styles.scss');`

I am able to use the class .test-css-class to style components.
However, I am not able to use the `$test-variable` variable in my application

```
.test {
    background-color: $test-variable;
}
```

I get an "undefined variable" compilation error.

Is importing such variable even possible ?

Comment: I have the same problem. Who can solve it?

Comment: For me it seems to work like this: `@use "my-lib/src/library/styles";`